# Most efficient method to print "test"?

Tags: c

To print something while consuming the least amount of resources.

it can even be a `0` or `1` not necessarily `test`

```
fputs("test",stdout);
printf("%s", "test");
puts("test");
```

Which one of the above commands is the most efficient ?

is there something else that is more efficient ?

Comment: What kind of "resources" (time, memory...) ?

Comment: The internal implementation of these functions is not regulated by any standard. One can implement them as inefficient as they want.

Comment: You could use the POSIX-defined function [`write()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/write.html)
directly instead of making the standard I/O library use it indirectly.  You should decide whether you want a newline at the end of the output — `puts()` adds it, the others don't (and neither does `write()`).  There are ways to deal with that, such as using the string `"test\n"` to more esoteric techniques using [`writev()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/writev.html), etc.  However, on a string as short as `test`, efficiency is a red herring.

Comment: I downvoted the question. You could easily test it yourself. This question is just an example of laziness. Write couple of the test programs, compile them with different compilers and run under different OS (for example windows linux). And you are done in 15 minutes.

Comment: @Chris Cousins our time to read it

Comment: 10 instructions in the C code, 10000 in the OS/driver.   Essentially no difference...

Comment: The benchmark probably does more than just write `"test"`, with or without the newline. It might do it a lot — maybe millions of times. In that case, you do lots of system calls.  However, if you're just writing 4 or 5 characters, then standard I/O (on Unix-like systems) ends up calling `write()`, as well as other code to manage buffering, etc.  So, it depends on what you're measuring.  This is why benchmarking is hard.  Are you comparing like with like?  What are you measuring?  (With just 5 bytes to write, the program start-up and shut-down overhead is bigger than the `write()` time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are basically two answers here.

(1) For just about all practical purposes, there is *no* difference in performance (time or other resources used) between

```
puts("test");
fputs("test\n",stdout);
printf("%s\n", "test");
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", "test");
```

(There are a few differences with respect to newline handling, as shown.)

Use whichever one is clearest and makes sense for your program; don't worry about efficiency here.

(2) Any question of the form "which of these is fastest?" can be answered only in the context of a particular environment, and cannot in general be predicted.  If you really care, you basically have no other option than to perform an empirical test, in your exact environment.  Beware that since the differences in performance are likely to be slight at best (see answer 1), you may have to perform thousands or millions of tests in order to get a statistically significant answer -- and this pretty much reinforces the point that, practically, any differences probably don't matter.

---

Now, just for fun, I ran a test.  Here is a little program to test all four alternatives, along with the low-level `write` system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main()
{
    int count = 100000000;
    time_t t1, t2;
    int delta;
    int i;

    t1 = time(NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) puts("test");

    t2 = time(NULL);
    delta = (int) t2 - t1;

    fprintf(stderr, "test 1: %d secs (%f prints/sec)\n",
        delta, (double)count/delta);

    t1 = t2;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) fputs("test\n", stdout);

    t2 = time(NULL);
    delta = (int) t2 - t1;

    fprintf(stderr, "test 2: %d secs (%f prints/sec)\n",
        delta, (double)count/delta);

    t1 = t2;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) printf("%s\n", "test");

    t2 = time(NULL);
    delta = (int) t2 - t1;

    fprintf(stderr, "test 3: %d secs (%f prints/sec)\n",
        delta, (double)count/delta);

    t1 = t2;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", "test");

    t2 = time(NULL);
    delta = (int) t2 - t1;

    fprintf(stderr, "test 4: %d secs (%f prints/sec)\n",
        delta, (double)count/delta);

    t1 = t2;

    for(i = 0; i < count; i++) write(1, "test\n", 5);

    t2 = time(NULL);
    delta = (int) t2 - t1;

    fprintf(stderr, "test 5: %d secs (%f prints/sec)\n",
        delta, (double)count/delta);
}
```

You will notice that I have chosen to run each test *one hundred million times*.  (I wasn't kidding when I said "you may have to perform thousands or millions of tests".)  Nevertheless, here are the results:

```
test 1: 9 secs (11111111.111111 prints/sec)
test 2: 8 secs (12500000.000000 prints/sec)
test 3: 17 secs (5882352.941176 prints/sec)
test 4: 16 secs (6250000.000000 prints/sec)
test 5: 45 secs (2222222.222222 prints/sec)
```

So, in one sense, my answer (1) was wrong.  There is a difference: `puts` and `fputs` are about twice as fast as `printf` and `fprintf`, at least on my machine.  But the fact I had to call them a hundred million times in order to see this difference shows that, on a modern machine, if you're making only a few tens or hundreds or thousands or even millions or tens of millions of calls, you likely won't see any difference at all.

[P.S. My test program isn't strictly portable.  I should have used `long int` for the counter.]

Comment: How does `write( STDOUT_FILENO, "test\n", 5UL );` perform?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Look at the code -- that's basically test 5.  It's significantly slower, as I'd expect.  stdio buffering is generally a win.

Comment: Ah, my mistake.  Confused by a scroll bar.  I'm really surprised a simple `write()` is three times slower than `fprintf( stderr, "%s\n", "test" );`  I suspect some type of optimization there.

Comment: @AndrewHenle As far as I know, the optimization is called "buffering".  System calls like `write` can be expensive.  (Back in they day, they could be 10-100 times as expensive as an ordinary function call.  Today it's not so bad.)  Calling `write` to print a few characters at a time is a terrible waste; letting stdio save up a bunch of to-be-written characters in a buffer, and not call `write` on the buffer until it's got 412 or 1024 or 8192 of them, is a big win, as I said.

Comment: "As far as I know, the optimization is called "buffering". ..." `stderr` is normally entirely unbuffered.

Comment: @SteveSummit About buffering: stdio is line buffered if the output is a tty. I guess you tested the same way I tested, piping the output to /dev/null ;) In that case, stdout is fully buffered. I ran your test program under strace, and its output clearly shows that stdout is buffered. IOW, the test is a bit skewed. If the output was a tty, I'd assume much less difference between puts(), printf("test\n"), and write(). YMMV

Comment: @AndrewHenle Sure, `stderr` isn't buffered, but the bulk of my test program's output went to `stdout`.

Comment: @BjornA.Agreed on all points.  I did indeed redirect to /dev/null.  But if anything that makes `puts` and `fputs` look better, because if the i/o were to something real, the contribution of the actual i/o would be greater, and the difference between (f)puts vs. (f)printf correspondingly less.  But the other thing is, if the OP is worried about i/o efficiency, it's probably to a file (i.e. fully buffered), not to a tty.

Comment: Footnote: Prompted by the comments from @BjornA. , I ran the same test program with output redirected to an actual file, instead of /dev/null.  The timings for `puts`, `fputs`, `printf`, and `fprintf` were essentially unchanged.  The time for `write`, however, ballooned to 155 sec.  (That is, when writing to a real file, a hundred million 5-byte writes are over 10 times slower than buffered stdio output.  Again, on my machine; YMMV.)

Comment: @SteveSummit Thanks for testing. Weird numbers, though. I reduced the count to 10 and ran your program using strace. Here's the output https://pastebin.com/VGtrh4XH
As one can see, all tests end up in 10 identical calls to write(). I wonder why test#5 seems to be so slow. Gut feeling says that test #5 should be faster since it does less (no printf involved. No adding of newline char) Any ideas?

Comment: @BjornA.I ran the program again without redirecting its output, so that all output appeared in the terminal window.  In that scenario, all 5 tests took essentially the same amount of time: ~25s, for only 1e7 prints.  This was because (a) the output was unbuffered (meaning that each stdio call resulted in a `write` of 5 bytes), and (b) because screen i/o is evidently much slower (by about a factor of 5), such that it dwarfed any differences in performance between the higher-level calls.

Answer (score 5):

There is essentially no difference in execution time between the three alternatives and some optimizing compilers will actually convert the `printf` to a call to something like `fputs`. So go for the one which does what you want in what you consider the clearest way.

Note that `puts("test");` writes a newline after the word. If you want the newline, that may well be the cleanest solution. If you don't want the newline, use one of the other two.

When trying to optimise code, focus on the big picture. Are you using the best algorithm? Are you performing unnecessary work? Could you use a better data structure? Trust the people who wrote the compiler and the standard library to have done a good job of optimising common idioms. They're excellent programmers and their job is to focus on the little details which will make your code run faster.

Comment: I do not agree. printf will be the slowest as it does much more than only display the string.

Comment: @Bjorn A. it is too broad question, as we have many compilers, many standard library implentations etc. I have downvoted the OPs question for the reason explained in the comment. We waste our time answering and discussing this kind of questions Satura could test it himself, instead of asking. PS my gcc 7.1 calls printf when format & the string are literals

Comment: @PeterJ And I upvoted your downvote. The question is silly. BTW, my previous comment was incorrect, which is why I deleted it. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: No worries :) BTW haven't you noticed that people are getting more & more lazy?

Comment: @PeterJ Not sure what you mean by silly, but I do feel that lots of questions could've been solved easily with a little effort by the many OPs. Hell, even Google can answer most of the C questions we get these days. Just my 2 cents...

Comment: @peterj: https://godbolt.org/g/Nx38m7 (of course, it can only call `puts` if the output ends with a newline). (Clang 4 does it, too: https://godbolt.org/g/DakNS4)

Comment: @PeterJ_01 "printf will be the slowest."  I do not agree. :-)
On my machine (a 5-year-old consumer-grade laptop), for 10,000 calls, under all circumstances, the timing is *identical*, to three decimal places.